# Plot multiple Y points per X point

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I would like to plot multiple y-axis points for each x-axis point.  Let me provide a M(N)WE to demonstrate what I want to do:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rand.seed(10)
seeds = range(0, 10)
data = np.empty((len(seeds), 2))
for n in seeds:
    data[n, 0] = rand.gauss(1, 0.01)
    data[n, 1] = rand.gammavariate(1, 0.01)
data = data.T

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(6, 6))

ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1:], s=10, facecolors="k", rasterized=True, zorder=1)
```

Running this will of course give the following error:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Naturally.  After all, there are 9 y-axis points for each x-axis point.  Yet printing out the length of `data[:, 0]` and `data[:, 1:]` shows that they both have length 2.  A natural way for matplotlib to interpret this is that each point in the n-th row of the y-axis array is assigned to the n-th point in the x-axis array.  My question is how do I do this directly?  Many indirect methods exist (such as making a list of the x-axis point's value that's the same length as your y-axis point array), but I'm looking for a way to do it directly.

Comment: I think the only ways are what you would consider "indirect" methods. matplotlib just wants `x` and `y` to match up, so any working method will end up with reshaped `x` and `y`.

Comment: `ax.scatter(np.tile(data[:, 0], data.shape[1]-1), data[:, 1:], ...)` ?

Comment: If you use plot instead of scatter this works.